# IP Address range for Azure Notification Hub

Tags: azure, ip-address, azure-notificationhub

I'm communicating from a protected server to an Azure Notification Hub service, using the endpoint provided by Azure (https://.servicebus.windows.net) -> 23.100.11.236

I need to open a firewall from my protected server to Azure. I can only do it using an IP address not a domain name.

I appreciate from other answers on Stack Overflow that it is not possible to have a static IP address assigned, and that the IP address could change over time.

I have two questions:

1. In your experience, how often does such an IP address actually change?
2. Is there an IP address RANGE which would remain valid, even if the specific IP within the range changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers inline..

1.In your experience, how often does such an IP address actually change?
 The IP addresses don't change often but there is no guarantee they never will.

2.Is there an IP address RANGE which would remain valid, even if the specific IP within the range changes?
 Refer to this link for the range of Azure IP Address range per datacenter:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653

You can whitelist all the IP Ranges for the datacenter your NotificationHub is in.

PS: You should check that link for any new additions to IP ranges.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - I'd searched for such a list but not found it. The download file gives all the IP ranges used by the Azure data centres including the one we use (Europe West) - which I can give to our firewall team to whitelist. Good to know that in practice existing ones don't appear to change that often.